# show gif image in imageview Android

Tags: android, image, android-studio, imageview, gif

A very strange behaviour, while writing code for showing GIF image in image-view.
what i am doing is

```
 InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.logo);
```

logo is gif image that is in the drawable folder.

**when I write that line of code in Eclipse , image loads successfully but when I import that code on Android Studio What I am seeing is an error on R.drawable.logo**

and the error is

**Expected Resource of type raw**
**supplying the wrong type of resource identifier. For Example when calling Resources.getString(int id), You should be passing R.string.something not R.drawable.something**

one code runs on Eclipse not on Android Studio

I am sure that no problem with the imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some R&D i have found a work-around for that

and that is instead of creating drawable folder and put that image into it

create assets folder in main/src/assests and paste that image and then open Input steam.

```
InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("logo.gif");
```

that worked for me but sill dont know the answer why

```
  InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.logo);
```

was not working.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using ion https://github.com/koush/ion#load-an-image-into-an-imageview is a nice library for load images and support gif from local store , resorces or from Url.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is using **Glide** library

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
```

And Load your ImageView

```
Glide.with(YourActivity.this).load(R.drawable.your_gif).into(yourImageView);
```